# Duplicate a single row at index?

Tags: python, pandas

In the past hour I was searching here and couldn't find a very simple thing I need to do, duplicate a single row at `index` x, and just put in on `index x+1`.

df

```
  a  b
0 3  8
1 2  4
2 9  0
3 5  1
```

copy index 2 and insert it as is in the next row:

```
  a  b
0 3  8
1 2  4
2 9  0
3 9  0 # new row
4 5  1
```

What I tried is concat(with my own columns names) which make a mess.

```
line = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "event": None}, index=[index+1])
return pd.concat([df.iloc[:index], line, df.iloc[index:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

How to simply duplicate a full row at a given index ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repeat()`. Fill in the dictionary with the index and the key, and how many extra rows you would like to add as the value. This can work for multiple values.

```
d = {2:1}
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.index.map(d).fillna(0)+1)].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   index  a  b
0      0  3  8
1      1  2  4
2      2  9  0
3      2  9  0
4      3  5  1
```

Comment: thanks! and what if i wanted to insert different values for a/b, and also to avoid creating a new column "index" (as you did) ? so the solution should look just like my example with different a/b values

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
df.loc[index+0.5] =  df.loc[index].values
return df.sort_index().reset_index(drop = True)
```